# Register/Login Woocommerce link not working

Tags: css, woocommerce

I´m not able to click the Register/Login link in my website. It only works if I scroll down the page, and then scroll back up. So I believe this is a CSS bug. I´ve tried to fix it, change the code directly on the page, but no success.

This is the webpage: https://www.pdrtech.com.br/ (sorry it is in Portuguese, but the link title is "Cadastrar ou Logar" on the top right corner).

I don´t know whatelse to try, so any ideas are very welcome.

Thanks,

Marcel.

Comment: Div with `.sticky-navigation-holder` sits on top of the div with an id of `sns_topheader`. After scrolling a style of top: -150px; is applied. Then everything works fine, so my best guess would be to check the corresponding Javascript.

Comment: This is very helpful @MathijsRutgers! Actually, if I don´t display this div (which is my sticky menu), the register link works fine. Unfortunately, I don´t know much javascript in order to fix it, but I´d rather have this link working than a sticky menu. Thank you for the tip!

Comment: Glad it helped you! :) You might want to look at how to do this with some javascript and css. This might get you started: https://css-tricks.com/scroll-fix-content/